# Do 3D modellers get to keep their models?

Tags: 3d, modeling

So after a modeller has finished their work on a game or a CGI asset in a film, is the person who created the model allowed to keep said asset once the project is completed?

Comment: Most companies retain IP rights to work you do while in their employ.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what kind of contract that person has and under what countrys laws that work was done.

Most likely the answer is NO. Because it is something that is tightly tied to the business, and thus the company almost certainly required it to be exclusively theirs.